# Django, How to Download a Docx file, or any file in general

Tags: html, django, download, docx

My current website creates and saves a Docx file to the server based on the the current users inputs/information.  I have the program saving it to the server, so the user can access it later.  So I am assuming the docx file can be considered static?  Well anyways, I am having trouble getting the download to work.

I have looked at many different threads on how to get a Docx to download and none have worked for me so far.
1.  [Downloadable docx file in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400089/downloadable-docx-file-in-django)
2.  [Django create .odt or .docx documents to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356496/django-create-odt-or-docx-documents-to-download)
[Generate the MS word document in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821352/generate-the-ms-word-document-in-django)

The closest I have gotten, was a docx file that downloaded, but the content was the path and not the actual docx file that I wanted.  Hoping someone can help, Thanks.

Code:

```
response = HttpResponse('docx_temps/extracted3/test.docx', content_type='application/vnd')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.doc'
return response
```

Code for Link, Still cannot get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="users/Tyler/Desktop/Django_Formatically/mysite/Formatically/docx_temps/extracted3/test.docx"
  download="Test.docx"> 
   Test.docx
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: you beat me too it

Comment: Really, what I am trying to do, is to have the user download a file (docx) that is saved on the server somewhere.

Comment: Why don't you just create a hyperlink and point it to the `.docx` file?

Comment: I tried that first, could not get it working though.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution A - static files

To be able to download a file considered *static* it has to be served in a way. In a production environment this task likely will be handled by a webserver like Apache or nginx.

To serve your media root via Django development server you can add the following pattern to your `urls.py`:

```
# urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    (r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

So any path below `/media/` will be served directly. You also have to make sure you have correctly set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in your settings:

```
# settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = 'Users/Tyler/Desktop/Django_Formatically/mysite/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

However - this approach does not allow you to interact on the Django level. So you cannot e.g. check for user permissions or track/log requests in Django. Every user knowing the URL to a file is able to access it.

#### Solution B - through Django view

```
    # views.py
    def file_view(request):

        filename = '<path to your file>'
        data = open(filename, "rb").read()
        response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/vnd')
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)

        return response
```

This is just the most simple way that has some drawbacks. The whole file content is loaded in python - so it is not very efficient when sending large files and having a lot of requests. A solution using `FileWrapper` can be found here: [Serving large files ( with high loads ) in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600843/serving-large-files-with-high-loads-in-django)

Or you could use [django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile) which allows easy use of Apache [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) or nginx [XSendfile](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile).